# Operand should contain 1 column(s) on DELETE but only 1 column selected

Tags: mysql, select, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a few rows from a MySQL table called 'lista_difusion_wp'.
I need to delete only the columns present on the table '_clientes_nowp' so I selected the common column in both tables. But the result is always the same: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Here is the query:

```
DELETE FROM
lista_difusion_wp
WHERE
lista_difusion_wp.cliente_id IN (
SELECT
id_cliente AS cliente_id 
FROM
_clientes_nowp)
```

I'm only selecting one column but still having troubles with this. Can you help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please add sample data from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem;

```
DROP TABLE if exists lista_difusion_wp,_clientes_nowp;
create table lista_difusion_wp(cliente_id int);
create table _clientes_nowp(id_cliente int);

insert into lista_difusion_wp values (1),(2),(3);
insert into _clientes_nowp values (1),(3);

DELETE FROM lista_difusion_wp
WHERE lista_difusion_wp.cliente_id IN (
        SELECT
        id_cliente AS cliente_id 
        FROM
        _clientes_nowp) ;

select * from lista_difusion_wp;

+------------+
| cliente_id |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The error does not appear to be from the published code - please check for triggers.